# How do I get the node name of parameter in XSLT template?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to update some XSLT to accomodate a new XML input format. The new structure pretty much breaks my former template logic, but I'm trying to keep from having to rewrite the whole thing over.

Essentially, I'd like to grab the name of a template parameter, remove a prefix, and use the result in an `<xsl:value-of/>`. For example:

```
<!-- calling location -->
<xsl:call-template name="myTemplate">
    <xsl:with-param name="field" select="Name"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<!-- template to do the processing. -->
<xsl:template name="myTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="field"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="replace($field, 'Prefix', '')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The context.

This is more of a over all since I have been asked to provide both the essence of the question and the over all context. A simplified version of my stylesheet can bee seen below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','" />
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xa;'" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry/Dependents"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="Address"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="Phone"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry/Dependents">
        <xsl:call-template name="valueOrParentOrNone">
            <xsl:with-param name="fieldValue" select="Name"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>

        <xsl:call-template name="valueOrParentOrNone">
            <xsl:with-param name="fieldValue" select="Address"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimeter"/>

        <xsl:call-template name="valueOrParentOrNone">
            <xsl:with-param name="fieldValue" select="Phone"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="valueOrParentOrNone">
        <xsl:param name="fieldValue"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Use passed in node if exists -->
            <xsl:when test="$fieldValue">
                <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue" />
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Use parent node of the same name if exists -->
            <xsl:when test="../$fieldName">
                <xsl:value-of select="../$fieldName" />
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Use "None" -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>"None"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Original input XML:

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <Name>J. Smith</Name>
        <Address>1123 XML Lane</Address>
        <Phone>123-456-7890</Phone>
        <Dependents>
            <Name>S. Smith</Name>
            <Address>1123 XML Lane</Address>
            <Phone>123-456-0987</Phone>
        </Dependents>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <Name>L. Hines</Name>
        <Address>423 Programming Way</Address>
        <Dependents>
            <Name>P. Hines</Name>
        </Dependents>
    </entry>
</root>
```

New Input XML

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <Name>J. Smith</Name>
        <Address>1123 XML Lane</Address>
        <Phone>123-456-7890</Phone>
        <DependentName>S. Smith</DependentName>
        <DependentAddress>1123 XML Lane</DependentAddress>
        <DependentPhone>123-456-0987</DependentPhone>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <Name>L. Hines</Name>
        <Address>423 Programming Way</Address>
        <DependentName>P. Hines</DependentName>
    </entry>
</root>
```

You'll notice that not all of the values are available in either format above. I need to reuse the parent values when the dependent value doesn't exist. If neither exists, I need to use the value of "None".  Input format changed so that the `Dependents` sibling no longer exists. Instead, the children of the `Dependents` has been raised to be siblings to the regular person values and are now a direct child of `entry`.

Intended output.

```
"J. Smith","1123 XML Lane","123-456-7890"
"S. Smith","1123 XML Lane","123-456-0987"
"L. Hines","423 Programming Way",,
"P. Hines","423 Programming Way","None"
```

EDIT: Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: Please don't use sample XML that says `<node1>`, `<node2>`, etc. when your nodes don't really have a counter in their names. For the people who try to answer your question it's very hard do write XSLT against such XML. Also, fix the syntax errors in your samples and make them so that they fit your XSLT code - or remove all parts from of your XSLT code that have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Okay, there's still some `functx:stripCommas()` business going on that doesn't really have any impact, but it's better. For the future: Reducing a question to the essence is beneficial to people who answer, for the next person who finds the question, and not at least for you, as it helps fleshing it out in your own head.

Comment: Thanks, @Tomalak. I removed those as well. I was hoping that the context of the situation would be helpful. I suppose not.

Comment: @jktravis Which XSLT processor are you using? The question - in its new form - calls for dynamic evaluation of a node's name.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Saxon 9.7.

Comment: You might want to look into Saxon extensions (or XSLT 3.0) for dynamic evaluation of  `substring-after(name($field), 'Dependent')` - but IMHO you will be better off rewriting the logic with explicit names,(assuming you know them in advance).

Comment: I do know the names. They are identical to the prefixed ones, but without the prefix. It's sounding like you're right though. That's going to be a mess. =/

Comment: Sorry, guys. I updated again to remove all the context. It's much more focused on the problem. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @jktravis, Please, provide the wanted result from the transformation. As it is now, it isn't clear what exactly must be accomplished, and I wouldn't be surprised that a simpler solution than the one you have in mind, might exist.

Comment: @jktravis, See my updated solution. You can choose between the one-liner or the 15-line accepted solution ... :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev. I think editing my template to add an additional parameter will work. I didn't even think of it, to be honest. I was so focused on trying to rewrite the template to not have to update the calls, that I didn't even consider it. Although, to answer your question, basically, I'm outputting a CSV with the person and dependents on different lines and falling back to the person's info when the dependent value isn't provided.

Comment: @jktravis, When one asks an XSLT question, the question isn't well defined if there isn't a complete example with source XML document (that you have), wanted result (literally provided -- not just verbally described), and the rules (constraints) that the transformation must implement. From all 5 edits of this question, I suspect that the transformation must rename certain elements according to some, not specified conditions. However, you are asking for implementing a simple choice b/n 2 strings (but referring to one of the strings as an element) and this is really confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still there are questions: How does the string  "234-907-1243"  appear in the results? It isn't in the source XML document. Also, from the updated question I believe that I should discard the 1st XML document and only consider the 2nd?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @DimitreNovatchev. It would actually just be an empty value. I've updated it appropriately. And yes, the 2nd XML is what I'm working with now. The previous was to provide the context of what I am working from.

Comment: Shouldn't this: `L. Hines","423 Programming Way",,` be actually: `L. Hines","423 Programming Way", "None"`  ?

Comment: The template `valueOrParentOrNone` isn't being used on the main person. Just the dependent. So, it would end up just being an empty value.

Comment: Are you sure that an empty value that is the last in the CSV should be denoted by `,,` ? Doesn't this mean "an empty value and another, missing value"?

Comment: It's fine. That's basically how it's working now anyhow.

Comment: @jktravis, See a complete, transformation - just 30 lines long when well formatted for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, your best bet would be to rewrite your template as:

```
<xsl:template name="valueOrAltOrNone">
    <xsl:param name="field"/>
    <xsl:param name="alt-field"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$field">
            <xsl:value-of select="$field" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$alt-field">
            <xsl:value-of select="$alt-field" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>"None"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and call it as (for example):

```
<xsl:call-template name="valueOrAltOrNone">
    <xsl:with-param name="field" select="DependentName"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="alt-field" select="Name"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

There is probably a shorter solution to do same, but I wanted to minimize the required changes.

Comment: I think that part is okay. What I want to avoid is having to move away from my `valueOrParentOrNone` template since the node names now have a prefix of `Dependent` (previously `Another`, but I updated the example code.) Previously, the logic was, "if the child node exists, use it, if not, use the parent's value of the same node name. If that's not available, just use None."

Answer (score 1):

**Just use**:

```
  <xsl:sequence select="($fieldValue[.], replace($fieldValue, 'Dependent', ''),'None')[1]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how I would apply this to my situation, though. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @jktravis, With this description of the question, the OP (you) is certainly the one that needs elaborating. The question, with its 5 edits, is totally confusing. After reading it for the past hour I still don't really know what is actually wanted. Did you see that Tomalak gave it up and deleted his answer?

Comment: I know. I had much more context earlier, but was asked to reduce the question to it's core. The accepted solution works around my issue, and gets me to where I need to be.

Comment: @jktravis, Well, by not explaining well the problem you miss the chance of being given a much better solution than the one you had in mind, and thus you are missing the chance of learning. Looking at the provided code I am sure that this code may not be necessary at all in a good solution, and I am willing to provide such solution, in case the problem was described properly.

Comment: I've updated to add the context back in. Let me know if it's still confusing.

Comment: @jktravis, The updated code isn't confusing. The question will become even more clear if you delete the 1st XML document as it isn't a logical and connected part of the question anymore. Please, see my new answer for a complete and short transformation.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:f="my:f">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="entry">
   <xsl:value-of select="string-join(
      (string(Name), string(Address), string(Phone), ''[not(current()/Phone)]),
       ','), 
      '&#xA;'"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="dependent"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="entry" mode="dependent">
   <xsl:value-of select="string-join(
     (f:getValue(.,Name, DependentName), f:getValue(.,Address, DependentAddress), 
      f:getValue(.,Phone, DependentPhone)),','), 
      '&#xA;'"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="f:getValue">
   <xsl:param name="pParent" as="element()"/>
   <xsl:param name="pChild" as="xs:string?"/>
   <xsl:param name="pdepChild" as="xs:string?"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vUsethis" select="($pdepChild, $pChild)[1]"/>

   <xsl:sequence select="($vUsethis[.],'None')[1]"/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <Name>J. Smith</Name>
        <Address>1123 XML Lane</Address>
        <Phone>123-456-7890</Phone>
        <DependentName>S. Smith</DependentName>
        <DependentAddress>1123 XML Lane</DependentAddress>
        <DependentPhone>123-456-0987</DependentPhone>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <Name>L. Hines</Name>
        <Address>423 Programming Way</Address>
        <DependentName>P. Hines</DependentName>
    </entry>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
J. Smith,1123 XML Lane,123-456-7890 
S. Smith,1123 XML Lane,123-456-0987 
L. Hines,423 Programming Way,, 
P. Hines,423 Programming Way,None
```